# Converting a Swift array of Ints into an array of its running subtotals

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have an `[Int]` array that looks like this:

```
1 2 1 4 3 ...
```

I want to transform it into an array of running subtotals that looks like this:

```
1 3 4 8 11 ...
```

It's easy enough to do using a `for` loop:

```
var subTotal = 0
var subTotalArray = [Int]()
for int in intArray {
    subTotal = subTotal + int
    subTotalArray.append(subTotal)
}
```

I'm just curious if there's a more elegant, tighter, and hopefully easy-to-read way of doing this using some of Swift's higher-order functions.